# Does Google Play Services make my app's APK bigger?

Tags: android, google-play-services

When I use the Google Play Services library in an Android project, does it get compiled with the APK and makes this bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will make your APK bigger. However you will have to try if it's really that much that it matters to you. Google says:

> The client library has a light footprint if you use [ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) as
>   part of your build process, so it won't have an adverse impact on your
>   app's file size.

Source: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html